# External Css is not working with my HTML code, what is my error?

Tags: css, html

[This is my HTML code which is not working in working with the css file located in other folder name css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQnpE.png)

[this is my css code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPjNr.png)

kindly help me and suggest me the correct changes.
Thank you

Comment: we need live preview, we are not fortune tellers

Comment: Can you please post the directory structure

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle for same. Also instead of attaching code images, add snippets in your question.

Answer (score 0):

How are your folders structured?

In the header of you HTML file you state that the css file is called 'home.css' and is located in a folder called 'css'. And this folder should be in the same directory as your html file.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can view your CSS file in your browser at the address you are specifying in your HTML. In other words, go to www.yourwebsite.com/css/home.css. If your CSS file does not show up, it is not at that address and you will need to determine where the file is actually located.

If you can view your CSS file at the address you have specified, but its style directives are not reflected on your pages, check to be sure they are not being overridden somewhere later in your CSS file.

As others have noted, your question is poorly formatted. Providing more information (i.e. URL, fiddle, directory structure, etc.) will likely get you more useful answers faster.